# interweave two data.frames in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rbind, do.call

I would like to interweave two `data.frame` in R. For example:

```
a = data.frame(x=1:5, y=5:1)
b = data.frame(x=2:6, y=4:0)
```

I would like the result to look like:

```
> x y
  1 5
  2 4
  2 4
  3 3
  3 3
  ...
```

obtained by `cbind`ing `x[1]` with `y[1]`, `x[2]` with `y[2]`, etc.

What is the cleanest way to do this? Right now my solution involves spitting everthing out to a list and merging. This is pretty ugly:

```
lst = lapply(1:length(x), function(i) cbind(x[i,], y[i,]))
res = do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by giving `x` and `y` an index, `rbind` them and sort by the index.

```
a = data.frame(x=1:5, y=5:1)
b = data.frame(x=2:6, y=4:0)
df <- rbind(data.frame(a, index = 1:nrow(a)), data.frame(b, index = 1:nrow(b)))
df <- df[order(df$index), c("x", "y")]
```

Answer (score 12):

There is, of course, the `interleave` function in the "gdata" package:

```
library(gdata)
interleave(a, b)
#    x y
# 1  1 5
# 6  2 4
# 2  2 4
# 7  3 3
# 3  3 3
# 8  4 2
# 4  4 2
# 9  5 1
# 5  5 1
# 10 6 0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'd approach:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(a, b))
dat[order(dat$x), ]
```

`do.call` was unnecessary in the first step but makes the solution more extendable.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is cheating a bit, but the (non-exported) function `interleave` from **ggplot2** is something I've stolen for my own uses before:

```
as.data.frame(mapply(FUN=ggplot2:::interleave,a,b))
```